# angular project css not loading .png image where as loads .jpg image

Tags: angular, image

```css
.mission {
 background: url("../../../assets/images/business-3152586_1920.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
}

.mission h3 {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.mission h3 span {
 font-weight: 700;
}

.mission h4 {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 25px;
    color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mission  agileits" id="mission">

  <h3>To deliver
   <span>Quality Output</span> -</h3>
  <h3>Unique, Affordable &amp; Professional</h3>
  <div class="lines  agileits">
   <div class="line1 w3l"></div>
   <div class="line2 aits">
    <h4>Our Mission...</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="line3 aits w3l"></div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

I am doing a project on angular. I am Using parallax scrolling effect.When i use .jpg image with same path it loads the image . But when i use png image from same path it shows error
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question to include the relevant CSS? Also, if its giving an error, it would be helpful if you could add the error as well. Thanks

Comment: is it due to image format? because .jpg image loads but .png shows error "(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:"  which is in same folder

Comment: And which version of Angular / angular-cli are you using?

Comment: angular 4.4.7 and cli-1.7.4

Comment: Looks like there's a known issue with 1.7... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9642 Can you try changing the path to `background: url("/assets/images/business-3152586_1920.png");`?